# "save link as" bulk download

Tags: hyperlink, save, bulk

I have a list of links in an html file and I want to perform a "save link as" for all of them so it downloads all the files into one folder.

Is this possible? I need to do this from within firefox or chrome as I am required to be logged in to the website,

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it's possible to do this with curl (including the login), I would recommend using a browser extension. Flashgot for Firefox is excellent, you can tell it to download all files of a certain extension, or do things like pattern matching.

http://flashgot.net/

Comment: Awesome. That's just what I wanted. I found a few others but they didn't quite cut it!